# Is there a way to check if there are any files uploading to an azure storage account container?

Tags: c#, azure-storage-account

I've got an api that allows a user to create a container in a storage account and then upload an unlimited number of files. At the point they've finished triggering the uploads they can trigger a process that will start validating those files and downloading to another machine. They can trigger this process before the uploads have finished.

So I was hoping to find a way where I can check whether a container has any file uploads in progress. I've not been able to find anything other than workarounds to track whether specific files are still uploading. I need to make a call to a container and see if anything is in progress or not.

Answer (score 0):

•   Yes, there is a way through which you can check whether the container has any file uploads in progress or not but for that purpose, you will have to **use the ‘FileUpload’ control option along with a Boolean value to verify whether that control has a file to upload or not**. In addition, **the ‘File.Exists’ method is called to check whether a file with the same name already occurs in the path. If it does, the name of the file to upload is prefixed with an underscore character before the ‘SaveAs’ method is called**.

**`Thus, atleast through this method, you can determine which files are in upload queue from a particular directory to the container`**. Please find the below snapshots and code snippets for your reference: -

```
   protected void  UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    // Before attempting to save the file, verify
    // that the FileUpload control contains a file.
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile) 
      // Call a helper method routine to save the file.
      SaveFile(FileUpload1.PostedFile);
    else
      // Notify the user that a file was not uploaded.
      UploadStatusLabel.Text = "You did not specify a file to upload.";
    }
```

**The above section of code states whether the file to be uploaded is present in the directory or not while the one below tries to find out whether a file with the same name already exists in the given path or not and prefixes it with a number so that when this file is being uploaded and queried for further, it can be identified**.

```
   if (System.IO.File.Exists(pathToCheck)) 
    {
      int counter = 2;
      while (System.IO.File.Exists(pathToCheck))
      {
        // if a file with this name already exists,
        // prefix the filename with a number.
        tempfileName = counter.ToString() + fileName;
        pathToCheck = savePath + tempfileName;
        counter ++;
      }
```

To know more details regarding this, I would suggest you to please refer the below link: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.hasfile?view=netframework-4.8#examples***

***https://www.educba.com/asp-dot-net-fileupload/***

[image: File Upload option]

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Azure Storage Account Containers?

Comment: Well, it can be useful to check if any files are in queue for uploading purpose from a specific directory to the said Azure Storage account container and thus will be helpful in that perspective.

Comment: Yes, but it's not answering the question I asked. There are plenty of examples out there showing how to do this, but not for checking if any files are uploading to an azure storage account container.